# Do DDS topics have to be defined the same way for every domain participant?

Tags: data-distribution-service

Let's say I have a topic defined as a union like this on one system:

```
union MyType switch (letterId) {
    case a: TypeA typeA;
    case b: TypeB typeB;
    case c: TypeC typeC;
};
```

But another system is not interested in the topic in the event that the union is sent in the form of TypeC. In fact, defining TypeC itself has a large amount of dependencies and it would be more convenient to just omit it. Can I then define the topic in system 2 as this since they will still have the same name?

```
union MyType switch (letterId) {
    case a: TypeA typeA;
    case b: TypeB typeB;
};
```

Would it just not work at all? If it would work what would happen when it does receive a TypeC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topics do not have to be defined in the exact same way for every DomainParticipant. The [OMG DDS-XTypes specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/DDS-XTypes/About-DDS-XTypes) describes how types of Topics can contain optional fields and how they can be extended or modified -- or not.

For DataWriters and DataReaders to match, their types need to be compatible according to the section *7.2.4 Type Compatibility* in the specification. That same section defines rules about how the assigning happens between compatible types that have different definitions.

For union types, the first row in *Table 7.17 - Definition of the is-assignable-from relationship for aggregated types* will tell you what you can do with your union definition while keeping it compatible between different versions.

As a quick assessment: *7.2.2.4.4.5 Optional Members* mentions that *Union members, including the discriminator, shall never be optional*, so you might have to find a creative solution for you particular situation.

Note that not all DDS vendors support the XTypes type system.

Comment: Ok, I use OpenSplice which does not appear to say anything about having this XTypes extension so looks like I am probably out of luck, but thank you for the answer.